# Need help to make that only two cards would be possible to click until they are matched

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, click

I'm new to javascript/jquery. I'm trying to create a card match game.
Need help to make that only two cards would be possible to click at the time. To prevent clicking while two cards being check if they match.

Tried to give unbind method to an element when there are in total two divs with .open class, but it removes the click event entirely, and to pass the click event back with (.bind('click' **function()**)) doesn't work, because I don't have a function to give as an argument.
Is there a way to do it or maybe I could do it differently? Thanks.

```js
$('.card').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('open flip');
      var numToMatch = $(this).find('.face').text();
      
   if($('.open').length === 2) {
      if($('.open').first().find('.face').text() == $('.open').last().find('.face').text()){
        $('.open').each(function() {
          $(this).removeClass('open').unbind('click');
        });
      } else {
          setTimeout (function(){
          $('.open').each(function() {
              $(this).removeClass('open flip');
            });
          }, 1000);
      };
    };
});
```

```css
* {
  maring: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.div-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 500px;
}

.card {
  width: 90px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.card.flip {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 5em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div-container'>
<div class='card'>
  <div class='back'></div>
  <div class='face three'>3</div>
</div>
<div class='card'>
  <div class='back'></div>
  <div class='face one'>1</div>
</div><div class='card'>
  <div class='back'></div>
  <div class='face one'>1</div>
</div><div class='card'>
  <div class='back'></div>
  <div class='face two'>2</div>
</div><div class='card'>
  <div class='back'></div>
  <div class='face two'>2</div>
</div><div class='card'>
  <div class='back'></div>
  <div class='face three'>3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems the example you posted is working perfectly fine. Could you elaborate on what the problem actually is?

Comment: The problem I have is that I want to be able to click only on two cards at a time (so only these two cards will be flipped) but in my sniped example you can quickly go clicking through all of the cards and they will be flipped. So instead you see two flipped cards it will be three or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you add the `open flip` class as soon as a `click` event has occurred. This is why it's possible to "spam click" and have more than 2 cards open at the same time. To prevent this, just change the first few lines of the click handler to this:

```
$('.card').click(function() {
    if($('.open').length >= 2)
        return;

    //... more code ...
});
```

If the amount of open cards is more than or equal to 2, simply return and don't handle the click event at all.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I wanted and works fine.